# iCal and Windows 7: Do they work together?

Tags: windows-7, sync, ipod, calendar, calendar.app

I'm about to buy an iPod touch, mainly because of the iCal. I'm a Windows user, so does anyone know if these two play well together? I'd prefer to be able to update my calendar from either the computer or iPod touch and sync.

I've searched Google, but I'm sceptic so far. Any experiences, knowledge you can send my way would be appreciated (and possibly save me money).

Thanks
Michael

Comment: I take it that's a NO then...

Comment: It does, check out thepurplepixel's answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Contrary to @Richard's answer, iTunes **will** sync your iPhone/iPod Touch's iCal to Outlook or Windows Live Calendar. When you plug your iPod in, you can select to *"Sync calendars from..."* and *"Sync contacts from..."*.